# Make ChangeDetectionStrategy configurable by component consumer

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

Say there's a component in a UI library that uses `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default`, but wants to give consumers the option of using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` instead (e.g. for performance-sensitive situations) via an `Input()` property.

Is it possible to change a component's change detection strategy at runtime? Or can it only be set in the `@Component` decorator?

Answer (score -1):

Could inject ChangeDetectorRef from '@angular/core' and call detectChanges() in a function that's triggered via an Input() property e.g.

```
// Import
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

//Constructor
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

//Function
input() {
  this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```